# main() within namespaces in C++

Tags: c++

While looking over some C++ code from a colleague, I saw the following:

```
...

namespace n1 {
namespace n2 {
namespace n3 {
namespace n4 {

int main(void) {
...
return 0;
}

}}}}

int main(void) {
return ::n1::n2::n3::n4::main();
}
```

This way of declaring the main function is possible and does compile, but I ask myself **why** one would do that and **if** one should do that.

I can see a possible reason, when one needs two main functions, but I honestly never encountered this.

So is this way of declaring the main function good practice or should it be avoided?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do whatever you like, personally this looks dumb and the wrong way to solve some unknown problem

Comment: For the "why?", ask your colleague. For the "if?", the answer is probably no.

Comment: this was probably done this way for reasons that cannot be infered from the code you show here. One can only guess, or ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: Well, I've worked on an application that had two run modes. One was as a tool that accepts a command line argument and does a job, and another as a process with GUI. It was convenient to do `if(has_argument()) WithGUI::main(); else Tool::main();`. Sometimes main is just the best name for it.

Comment: This may be a way to reuse some code from another project without modify it, but I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it...

Comment: @Hamed That's quite a different question.

Comment: My bad, Sorry..

Comment: This seems like a normal approach if `main` inside of namespaces is located in another file. This way file with "real" `main` only contains trivial stuff.

Comment: A key factor in this case is probably "because we can", rather than because of any particular need.

Comment: There's only one `main()` function in this program.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had a chance to ask my colleague about the **why**. The reason: In his old company, namespaces were used to specify the origin of the project (which company branch, which lab, which project). To be consistent, even the main function had to be within these cascaded namespaces. This makes it necessary to have the wrapped main function. So I will most likely not adapt this style...

Comment: @EdChum, I'm wondering how you can be so certain it's the *wrong* way to solve an *unknown* problem. Surely, if the problem is not known, no judgement calls can be made about the solution :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo gut feel, especially after now seeing the real reason it just looks like poor housekeeping that is brittle, also it's possible to have [`known unknowns`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns)